# Visual Studio 2015 asking for report viewer v14.0.0 when existing reports and references are v12.0.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am developing a classic ASP.NET Webforms App, but with an existing report and with every new one I create, I have an error on the .aspx file that goes like this `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies`.

I have checked references and reportviewer version on the toolbox, but everything is Version=12.0.0.0, the existing report was created using version 12, what I have to do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Below are possible solution to your issue...

1. Access the `cssproj` with notepad of the project and check whether in `<assemblies>` tag which ReportViewer version it is calling.
2. Delete Your `Reference` & re-add the reference of reportviewer.
3. Your system might not have ReportViewer installed.
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496
4. You might be having multiple version of Reportviewer. please check this link for solution in this case. [Microsoft ReportViewer 2012 Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114437/microsoft-reportviewer-2012-reference)